# text not appearing besides checkbox

Tags: html, css

I need to have checkbox and text appear on same line.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 20px;
  /*Desired width*/
  height: 20px;
  /*Desired height*/
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <label> BO Dashboard</label>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked>Access
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Control
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see in the snippet this is working fine. It seems you are using Bootstrap? Which version?

Comment: @Adi if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If not please write in the comments why or edit your question to make your problem more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
```

This will place the text of the inputs in the middle.
See the code below:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 20px; /*Desired width*/
  height: 20px; /*Desired height*/
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
   <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <label> BO Dashboard</label>
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked >Access
   </div>
   <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Control
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vertical-align:middle;`. The `vertical-align` property sets the vertical alignment of an element. The most common vertical-align properties are baseline, text-top, top, middle, bottom, text-bottom. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 20px;
  /*Desired width*/
  height: 20px;
  /*Desired height*/
  background: white;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <label> BO Dashboard</label>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked>Access
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">Control
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3
    </label>
  </form>
 </div>
```